# Terraform for_each iteration with the file function

Tags: foreach, terraform, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-cloud

My requirement is to create a dynamic resource Confluent Schema. Below is the **schema.tf** file.
Basically, need to include map type object and will be creating different Schema by passing name and file attributes. **What changes to be done on below highlighted "schema" file parameter so that it can be included in the for_each block?**

```
resource "confluent_schema" "sample_avro_schema" {
  schema_registry_cluster {
    id = confluent_schema_registry_cluster.essentials.id
  }
  rest_endpoint = confluent_schema_registry_cluster.essentials.rest_endpoint
  for_each      = toset(var.subject_name_avro)
  subject_name  = each.key
  format        = "AVRO"
  **schema        = file("modules/confluent_kafka_cluster_dedicated/schemas/sample_schema_avro.avsc")**
  credentials {
    key    = confluent_api_key.env-manager-schema-registry-api-key.id
    secret = confluent_api_key.env-manager-schema-registry-api-key.secret
  }
}
```

Variable declaration as below: variable.tf file

```
variable "subject_name_avro" {
  description = "AVRO Schema Name"
  type        = list(string)
  default     = ["avro-topic-value"]
}
```

And I am running this execution using .tfvars file:

```
subject_name_avro          = ["avro-topic-1-value"]
```

My requirement is to include below changes in .tfvars file. **Kindly suggest what resource and variable level changes to be done to include schema file parameter dynamically**.

```
subject_name_avro = [  
    {
        subject_name_avro  = "avro-topic-1-value"
        schema      = file("modules/confluent_kafka_cluster_dedicated/schemas/sample_schema_avro1.avsc")
    },  
    {
        subject_name_avro  = "avro-topic-2-value"
        schema      = file("modules/confluent_kafka_cluster_dedicated/schemas/sample_schema_avro2.avsc")
    },   
]
```

Sample file content "sample_schema_avro.avsc"

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "io.confluent.developer.avro",
  "name": "Purchase",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "item",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "amount",
      "type": "double"
    },
    {
      "name": "customer_id",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You forgot to explain what's wrong with the current code. Any errors? Also you did not provide the file content.

Comment: @Marcin - Hello, I do not have any error with the above code. I am able to create different schema, but with only one parameter i.e. Name. Basically, now I want to include Name and Schema file parameters combined together and pass it dynamically thorugh .tfvars file.
I am stuck at how to pass file parameters inside the for_each block and what resource and variables changes need to be made. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `file` in a variabiles. You can use only path in your case:

```
subject_name_avro = [  
    {
        subject_name_avro  = "avro-topic-1-value"
        schema      = "./modules/confluent_kafka_cluster_dedicated/schemas/sample_schema_avro1.avsc"
    },  
    {
        subject_name_avro  = "avro-topic-2-value"
        schema      = "./modules/confluent_kafka_cluster_dedicated/schemas/sample_schema_avro2.avsc"
    },   
]
```

To iterate over this you can use `count` or `for_each`. With `for_each` it would be:

```
resource "confluent_schema" "sample_avro_schema" {
  
  for_each      = {for idx, val in var.subject_name_avro: idx => val}
 
  schema_registry_cluster {
    id = confluent_schema_registry_cluster.essentials.id
  }
  rest_endpoint = confluent_schema_registry_cluster.essentials.rest_endpoint
  subject_name  = each.value.subject_name_avro
  format        = "AVRO"
  **schema        = file(each.value.schema)
  credentials {
    key    = confluent_api_key.env-manager-schema-registry-api-key.id
    secret = confluent_api_key.env-manager-schema-registry-api-key.secret
  }
}
```